# Review audit is missing tags

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I encountered a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1636971) for a question without tags.

> A question without tags? Suspicious... Aha - a review audit!

Comment: Likely those who don't notice it's a bad suggestion won't notice the missing tags as well. :-)